# How to use AppAuth-Android with IdentityServer4?

Tags: android, identityserver4

I have successfully configured a Identityserver4 for my ASP.Net MVC client, and everything is working fine.
Now I'm looking to develop an Android app client. The MVC client and the Android client uses the same Identity Server for authentication and authorization.
So for Android client I'm looking for ["AppAuth-Android"](https://github.com/openid/AppAuth-Android) GitHub library. But I couldn't find any sample or help to use the library with IdentityServer4. I have read the documentation of the "AppAuth-Android" library and it says

> In general, AppAuth can work with any Authorization Server (AS) that supports native apps.

So my question is 1) how can I configure my Identity Server to work with Android app.
2) How to authenticate my Android app with the help of "AppAuth-Android".

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Can some one please create a tag for "AppAuth-Android"?

Comment: From an IdentityServer point of view, configure the client for the hybrid grant type and required PKCE. Then turn on logging and see what happens when the client connects.

Comment: If you find an incompatibility between AppAuth and IdentityServer4 - please open an issue on the IS4 issue tracker.

Comment: Ok! I'll give it a try and update you. Thanks

Comment: If configured the client with hybrid grant type and required PKCE, I'm getting the error "Invalid grant type for client: authorization_code" in log.

Comment: If I changed the grant type to 'GrantTypes.Code', then everything is working fine. I couldn't find any option to change the grant type in AppAuth. Any ideas?

Comment: please check this: https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4/issues/479#issuecomment-269080200

Answer (score 1):

Basiclly, you can use following settings for identityserver4

```
new Client
           {
               ClientId = "client.android",
               RequireClientSecret = false,
               ClientName = "Android app client",
               AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.Code,
               RequirePkce = true,
               RequireConsent = false,

               RedirectUris = { "net.openid.appauthdemo://oauth2redirect" },
               AllowedScopes =
               {
                   IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.OpenId,
                   IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.Profile,
                   IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.Email,
                   IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.Phone,
                   "api1"
               },
               AllowOfflineAccess = true
           }
```

Anyway you can refer to https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4/issues/479 for more details about this issue.

Answer (score 1):

The data in the server side should be the same as the data used in the android app.

Add a client to the server side

```
  new Client
        {
            ClientId = "myClientId",
            ClientName = "myClientName",
            AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.CodeAndClientCredentials,
            RequireConsent = false,

            ClientSecrets =
            {
                new Secret("myClientSecret".Sha256())
            },

            RedirectUris = { "myRedirectUri://callback" },

            AllowedScopes =
            {
                IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.OpenId,
                IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.Profile,
                IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.Email,
                IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.Phone,
            },

            AllowOfflineAccess = true
        }
```

In the android app you should have the same `clientId`,`clientSecret`,`redirectUri` ..

I have made a sample using AppAuth-android library you should just edit the data in the `gradle.properties` check it [here](https://github.com/hadiidbouk/AppAuthIdentityServer4)

Comment: Please Edit your answer with details and solution not just a link

Comment: @I know this is a bit old, but I was wondering if you can tell me what the redirecdt URI is suppose to look like? Is it com.mysite.myapp or something else?